# Telnet smtp.mail - must issue STARTTLS command first

Tags: smtp, telnet

On my Mac terminal, I am trying to `telnet` into my `smtp.gmail.com` through `port 587`.

On Google Apps, (which is set to manage a Dreamhost domain), I have relay configured, as follows:

`"Allowed senders: Only addresses in my domains"` 
`"Require SMTP Authentication: Yes`"

when I `HELO <me@domain.com>`, I get:

`250 smtp.gmail.com at your service`

then I enter `MAIL FROM: <me@example.com>`

which returns:

`530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're required to start encrypting the connection first. This is done using the STARTTLS command.

You can use the following command instead of `telnet`:

`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -ign_eof -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587`

It works like the telnet command, but takes care of starting the encryption first.

Comment: This breaks when entering: `RCPT TO: myuser@googlemail.com` with `RENEGOTIATING<LF>139860672468096:error:1420410A:SSL routines:SSL_renegotiate:wrong ssl version:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2127:`

Comment: @rubo77, I got the same error. Have you gotten past it?

Comment: Actually the correct command would be: `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -ign_eof -crlf -connect <your.server>:port`. The documentation of s_client says it will do a Renegotiation when typing in a big `R` at the start of a line (here `RCPT TO...`). Since TLS1.3 doesn't support that, you get this strange error message.

Comment: @dCSeven Thanks for the improved `openssl` command line. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

## Connecting

If from command line on Mac and Linux one can use `openssl`. E.g:

```bash
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -4 -connect smtp.server.no:587 -crlf -ign_eof
```

`-4` can be needed to force IPv4.

If from command line on Windows, one should not use the `-crlf` option. E.g:

```bash
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -4 -connect smtp.server.no:587 -ign_eof
```

### Hello

On successful connection and the welcoming `250 HELP` do the normal `EHLO`:

```
EHLO nero<ENTER>
```

Yielding the server spec.

```
250-smtp.server.no Hello nero [1.2.3.4]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPE_CONNECT
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-CHUNKING
250 HELP
```

## Authentication

Here I'm covering `AUTH PLAIN` and `AUTH LOGIN`.

- For `LOGIN` we need base-64 for username and password.

  - `printf %s 'user' | base64` => `dXNlcg==`
  - `printf %s 'pass' | base64` => `cGFzcw==`
- For `PLAIN` we need base-64 for `0x00Username0x00Password`

  - `printf '\0%s\0%s' 'user' 'pass' | base64` => `AHVzZXIAcGFzcw==`

### `LOGIN`:

The login method commence as follows.

```
AUTH LOGIN<ENTER>
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dXNlcg==<ENTER>
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
cGFzcw==<ENTER>
235 Authentication succeeded
```

or (using username on AUTH line):

```
AUTH LOGIN dXNlcg==<ENTER>
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
cGFzcw==<ENTER>
235 Authentication succeeded
```

The responses are (in base-64):

- `VXNlcm5hbWU6` = `Username:`
- `UGFzc3dvcmQ6` = `Password:`

### `PLAIN`:

```
AUTH PLAIN<ENTER>
334
AHVzZXIAcGFzcw==<ENTER>
235 Authentication succeeded
```

Or AUTH, username and password in one line:

```
AUTH PLAIN AHVzZXIAcGFzcw==<ENTER>
235 Authentication succeeded
```

---

After this continue as normal with `RCPT TO` etc. or what ever.

Comment: Email doesn't send after typing a full stop on a blank line. How do you send the message and close the connection?

Comment: Fixed. I'll update edit the answer. You can't use the `-crlf` on Windows.